# laravel whereIn multiple columns

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, where-in

I am looking for laravel way for this query:

```
select * from `table` 
where (product_id, request_id) NOT IN ((66, 10),(76,23))
```

Perhaps something like:

```
$ids = =array(
    ['66', '10'],
    ['76', '23']
)
DB::table('table')->whereNotInMultiple(['product_id', 'request_id'], $ids)->get();
```

How do I do this in laravel?

Answer (score -1):

```
DB::table('table')->whereNotIn('product_id', ['66','10'])
->whereNotIn('request_id', ['76', '23'])->get();
```

Comment: This is not doing what the original SQL does. If there is a row of (product_id=66, request_id=1), it will still be in the result in the original SQL, but will be excluded using this code.