# Laravel QueryBuilder multiple columns match in the same WhereIn

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I would have liked to convert a SQL query like this one in Laravel Eloquent.
This query works on MariaDb but i don't know about other engines (might be the reason why it isn't implented):

| id | year | country | enabled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2000 | "France" | 0 |
| 1 | 2001 | "Spain" | 0 |
| 2 | 2002 | "France" | 1 |
| 3 | 2003 | "Germany" | 1 |

> SELECT id FROM my_db.countries WHERE (name, enabled) IN (("France", 1), ("Spain", 0));
>
> > This returns 1 and 2.

This is possible with Eloquent (as suggested here: [laravel whereIn multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56735665/laravel-wherein-multiple-columns) but it wouldn't return the expected results:

> DB::table('countries')->select('id')->whereIn('name', ["france", "Spain"])->whereIn('enabled', [0, 1])->all();
>
> > This returns 0, 1 and 2.

I gave a shot at adapting the Illuminate/Database library to fit my needs but the databinding started to get really complexe.

I managed to make it with a whereRaw query but it isn't really clean enough for production code as there are no data binding (values shows up with ->toSql()).

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query syntax you want to get:

```
SELECT id FROM my_db.countries WHERE (name, enabled) IN (("France", 1), ("Spain", 0));
```

is exclusive to Oracle. The whereIn method of Laravel supports (String, Array), so I think you only have the options to do it through raw queries or using the solution proposed by [V-K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3519720/v-k)

Comment: If i am not mistaken Oracle is MySql and the engine i am using is MariaDb (i double checked) and it works. But i guess that as MariaDb is a fork of MySql they share a lots of features. Anyway if it's only supported by those 2 engines it makes sens that Laravel Querybuilder doesn't feels like it has to support it as this behaviour can be simulated by @V-K answer. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you wanna get records that satisfy two conditions. `whereIn` checks if the column contains one of the values in the array.

```
`DB::table('countries')->select('id')->whereIn('name', ["france", "Spain"])->whereIn('enabled', [0, 1])->all();`
```

that code returns combinations france 0, france 1, Spain 0, Spain 1.
TO get combinations france 0 and Spain 1 you can use this code

```
DB::table('countries')
            ->select('id')
            ->where(function(Builder $builder) {
                $builder
                    ->where('name', 'france')
                    ->where('enabled', 0);
            })
            ->orWhere(function(Builder $builder) {
                $builder
                    ->where('name', 'Spain')
                    ->where('enabled', 1);
            })
            ->get();
```

It checks the conditions `name = france and enabled = 0` work together

Comment: I agree that would match what i'm looking for but i am actually trying to bind the id of a massive upsert of thousands of records. I am inclined to think that multiple columns in the same whereIn would be more optimized SQL wise and would really like a way to do it with this grammar. But i think that your solution is better than my current raw query even if it's only for the security. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

If you add a new column that will keep the concatenation of the `country` and `enabled` fields, then you can use a simple `whereIn` method.

| id | year | country | enabled | country_enabled |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2000 | "France" | 0 | "France-0" |
| 1 | 2001 | "Spain" | 0 | "Spain-0" |
| 2 | 2002 | "France" | 1 | "France-1" |
| 3 | 2003 | "Germany" | 1 | "Germany-1" |

```php
DB::table('countries')->select('id')->whereIn('country_enabled ', ["France-1", "Spain-0"])->get();
```

You may even add an index to that column to speed up the search.

Of course, the provided solution will add some slight overhead to the writing in that table.